# Problems with attribute binding and shaders

Tags: c#, opengl

Currently i'm upgrading our OpenGL-Engine to a new shading and attribute system which is more dynamic and are not somehow static in usage and programming.

For this i'm replacing the old `VertexBuffer` class with a new `BufferRenderer` to which multiple `DataBuffer` ( `RenderDataBuffer`, `RenderIndexBuffer` ) objects are assigned, those are holding my rendering data. This new system allows instancing with `glDrawElementsInstanced` and also static rendering with `glDrawElements`.

#### The Problem

It looks like a attribute corrupts a existing position attribute and leads to unexpected results. I tested this with different settings

#### Test setup

This code sets up the test data:

```
_Shader = new Shader(ShaderSource.FromFile("InstancingShader.xml"));
_VertexBuffer = new BufferRenderer();
RenderDataBuffer positionBuffer = new RenderDataBuffer(ArrayBufferTarget.ARRAY_BUFFER, ArrayBufferUsage.STATIC_DRAW, 
    new VertexDeclaration(DeclarationType.Float, DeclarationSize.Three, AttributeBindingType.Position));
// Set the position data of the quad
positionBuffer.BufferData(new[] { new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 0, 1) });

RenderDataBuffer instanceBuffer = new RenderDataBuffer(ArrayBufferTarget.ARRAY_BUFFER, ArrayBufferUsage.DYNAMIC_DRAW,
    new VertexDeclaration(DeclarationType.Float, DeclarationSize.Four, AttributeBindingType.Instancing),
    new VertexDeclaration(DeclarationType.Float, DeclarationSize.Four, AttributeBindingType.Color));
// Buffer the instance data
instanceBuffer.BufferData<InstanceTestData>(new[] {
        new InstanceTestData() { Color = Colors.Red, PRS = new Color(0.1f, 1f, 0.5f, 1) },
        new InstanceTestData() { Color = Colors.Blue, PRS = new Color(1f, 1f, 0.5f, 1) },
        new InstanceTestData() { Color = Colors.Green, PRS = new Color(0.1f, 1f, 1f, 1) },
        new InstanceTestData() { Color = Colors.Yellow, PRS = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 1) }
});
// Set up a index buffer for indexed rendering
RenderIndexBuffer indiciesBuffer = new RenderIndexBuffer(type: IndiciesType.UNSIGNED_BYTE);
indiciesBuffer.BufferData(new Byte[] { 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3 });

// Register the buffers ( second parameter is used for glVertexAttribDivisor )
_VertexBuffer.AddBuffer(positionBuffer);
_VertexBuffer.AddBuffer(instanceBuffer, 1);
_VertexBuffer.IndexBuffer = indiciesBuffer;
```

The vertex shader ( pixel just outputs the color ):

```
uniform mat4 uModelViewProjection;      
varying vec4 vColor;
attribute vec3 aPosition; // POSITION0
attribute vec4 aColor;   // COLOR 0
attribute vec4 aInstancePosition; // INSTANCING0


void main()
{    
    gl_Position = uModelViewProjection * vec4(vec2((aPosition.x * 20) + (gl_InstanceID * 20), aPosition.z * 20), -3, 1);
    vColor = aColor;
}
```

#### Rendering ( Pseudocode to simplify reading; Not final for all performance guys out there )

```
glUseProgram
foreach (parameter in shader_parameters)
    glUniformX

foreach (buffer in render_buffers)
    glBindBuffer
    foreach (declaration in buffer.vertex_declarations)
        if (shader.Exists(declaration)) // Check if declaration exists in shader
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader.attributeLocation(declaration))
            glVertexAttribPointer
            if (instanceDivisor != null)
                glVertexAttribDivisor
glBindBuffer(index_buffer)
glDrawElementsInstanced
```

#### Shader attribute binding

The shader attribute binding is done at initialization and looks like this:

```
_VertexAttributes = source.Attributes.ToArray();
for (uint i = 0; i < _VertexAttributes.Length; i++)
{
    ShaderAttribute attribute = _VertexAttributes[i];
    GLShaders.BindAttribLocation(_ShaderHandle, i, attribute.Name);
}
```

So there should be not attribute aliasing in the shader, each of them gets a unique number ( Matrices are not implemented yet, i know they require more than one index, but i'm also not using them as vertex attributes right now ). As mentioned in the comment, i filter the attributes after linking the shader so no location is bound which does not exists.

This is the code for the attribute binding:

```
Bind();
Int32 offset = 0;
for (UInt32 i = 0; i < _Declarations.Length; i++)
{
    VertexDeclaration data = _Declarations[i];
    ShaderAttributeLocation location;
    if (shader.GetAttributeLocation(data.Binding, out location))
    {
        GLVertexBuffer.EnableVertexAttribArray(location);
        GLVertexBuffer.VertexAttribPointer(location, (AttributeSize)data.Size, (AttributeType)data.Type, data.Normalized, _StrideSize, new IntPtr(offset));
        if (instanceDivisor != null)
            GLVertexBuffer.VertexAttribDivisor(location, instanceDivisor.Value);
    }
    offset += data.ComponentSize;
}
```

#### Test results

The results are as seen here:

[image: Working colors]

Now, if i change the binding on the code side ( `AttributeBindingType.Color` <-> `AttributeBindingType.Instancing` ) it looks like this:

[image: Working PRS]

If i change now `vColor = aColor;` to `vColor = aInstancePosition;` the results are simple: Instead of having multiple small quads with color i have one big fullscreen quad which is red. The locations of each of the attributes is different from the others so technically the values should be correct, but they seem to be not. Also using both attributes in the shader doesn't solve the problem.

I'm searching for a idea or solution to solve this problem.

#### Tracking the problem down

I've started to track it down more and more, with this complex code it costs me hours but i found something: The shader i'm using is only working when i leave out the attribute index 0 when calling `BindAttribLocation`. With other words this is a workaround which only works for the specified shader:

```
foreach (attribute in vertexAttributes)
{  
    if (shader == problemShader)
        // i is index of the attribute
        glBindAttribLocation(_ShaderHandle, i + 1, attribute.Name);
    // All other shaders
    else glBindAttribLocation(_ShaderHandle, i, attribute.Name); 
}
```

I guess it has something to do with either instancing or the multiple VBO's which i'm using for instancing. This are the only differences to the normal shaders. The normal ones are also only working when i start the attribute location index at 0, they are not working when starting at 1.

Comment: Because `aInstancePosition` is not used in your vertex shader, it actually has no attribute location in your linked program. Thus, though you may bind it to an attribute location, if you later query its location you will get nothing. Then if you try and exchange the location for `aColor` and `aInstancedPosition` as your question seems to describe at a later time, it will not work because one of them has no location.

Comment: Moreover, `attribute vec4 aInstancePosition // INSTANCING0;` is not even a valid statement, the semicolon is after the single-line comment. Can you possibly paste your actual shader to give a better idea what is going on?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I could also use it, won't make any difference. Also i bind the attribute and check them after linking if they exist. When binding the VBO to the shader locations i skip the missing location. The attribute is just a tipping error, the `// INSTANCING 0` does not exists in the original shader, the binding occurs somewhere else. Thank you so far.

Comment: I hope its clear that i use 3 VBO's here for rendering ( 1 index, 2 data ). I guess this might be the source of the problem.

Comment: is this link helpful ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572218/vertex-attribute-buffers-getting-bound-to-wrong-attribute

Comment: @KajalSinha Thank you for the link, but i'm really sorry to say its not! :-/ I'm creating the program before i bind the attribute locations. Anyway after binding i also get the actual position of the locations ( `CreateProgram` -> `AttachShader` -> `BindAttribLocation` -> `LinkProgram` ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem and it has been really simple.
After rendering with instancing i need to call `glVertexAttribDivisor(location, 0);` on the attributes which had the divisor enabled before.